# How to read complex variables?

Tags: php, variables, object, get

```
<?php
class config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if ($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit) {
                if (isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }

            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

I'am following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6vDgLwJ7n8&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc from phpacademy. I got lost and can't understand this lines

function get `($path = null)` ---- what does this mean? from my understanding it says "get the value of `$path`". but it leads me to another question, where can I get the value of `$path`? please enlighten me and translate this statement in english.

`if ($path)` ----- does this check if $path has a value?

`$config = $config[$bit]` ---- this is my first time to encounter this, I can't understand because there is a bracket with a variable in it. please enlighten me and teach me how can I translate this and read it in plain english.

Comment: Arrays tutorial: http://oreilly.com/catalog/progphp/chapter/ch05.html

Comment: Reference: [functions in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)

Comment: On a side note, you might want to find a better tutorial, because the code you are showing has a number of problems, e.g. it access global state and statics, which can easily lead to unmaintainable applications full of side effects and rigid, hard to change code.

Comment: Hi gordon, can you suggest a good one?

Answer (score 2):

```
function get($path = null)
```

That line declares a function named `get` which will accept one parameter named `path`. It has also provided a default value for `path` which is null. In plain that means if no path is sent to this function, then consider the path to be a `null` value.

This can be better explained with a different example

```
   function display($message="Hello World")  
   {
     echo $message;
   }
```

If this function is called like

```
display("Testing"); // It will output `Testing`
display(); // It will output `Hello World`
```

**Secondly**

```
$config[$bit];
```

Means the value in `$config` array which has an index which is stored in `$bit` variable.

For example

```
$a=array();
$a["test"]=1;
$index="test";

echo $a["test"];    //echoes 1
echo $a[$index];    //echoes 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get($path = null)
```

This is a function declaration where the default value for `$path` is already set. Nothing more or less. The default value is `NULL` which means ... well, nothing. You can still hand over an argument and overwrite the default.